# Cannot update to latest typescript using NPM

Tags: typescript, npm, npm-install

My **package.json** has Typescript set like this :

```
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "typescript": "^3.9.10"
  },
```

If I try to update to the latest typescript using this command :

```
npm install -g typescript@latest
```

I would expect my typescript entry to update to 4.5 or whatever it is.

After I run the install the **package.json** still displays typescript like this :

```
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "typescript": "^3.9.10"
  },
```

Why is this so? This is not how I understand NPM to work.

Comment: Remove the `-g` flag.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the `package.json` didn't update is that you provided the `--global` or `-g` flag to NPM in a local directory. When this flag is specified, NPM makes all executables in a package available in the `PATH` so you can run it on the command line. In other words, this is just updating your `tsc` command that you can run in the terminal. Removing that flag will update it in the local directory. Just run the same command like this:

```sh
npm install typescript@latest
```

Comment: You also might want to add --save. This tells npm you want to update the package.json as well as you node_modules folder.  You almost never need to omit --save.

Comment: @Aron `--save` is by default `true` (I think since `npm cli 5`)